# line separator, but with float text-left

Tags: html, css

i find many solution how to make line separator with text-align in center. But I need align text left. I try all solution, but no success.
i try with this code

```
 <body>
<h1>ODABERITE PAKET</h1>
```

and in css

```
h1 {
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
background-color: #000;
content: "";
display: inline-block;
height: 15px;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 50%;
}
h1:before {
right: 0.5em;
margin-left: -50%;
}
h1:after {
left: 0.5em;
margin-right: -0%;
}
```

But this not working like i expect. Text is bellow line. Thnx

EDIT: 
@Aaron Mahlke answer is solution

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: sure... here is plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gEYidUzZ49iafxhQvDiW?p=preview . If i put this between two div they dont show on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this will help?

```css
.sep{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.sep:before{
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sep:after{
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sep">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx @Aaron Mahlke this is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I did`n undrestand your question completly but at the first you can use

```
textalign-left; direction:ltr;
```

I not you answer?

Comment: I'll try to explain. So I need to put a line with text i middle. The example that I set on plunker, doing what I need, but when i put on my page, not at all shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```css
.dot{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:1px;
  border-top:1px dashed;
  margin-top:11px;
  
}
.txt{
float:left;
  margin:0px 5px;
}
.main{
width:250px;
  border:1px solid;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="dot"></div><span class="txt">Text</span><div class="dot"></div>
  <div>
```